# Bounds on a limit related to the Euclid numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

The Euclid numbers are defined recursively by $e_1 = 2$, and $e_{n + 1} = \prod_{k = 1}^n e_k + 1$ for all $n \geq 1$. They also satisfy $e_{n + 1} = e_n^2 - e_n + 1$ and $e_{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2} = (e_n - \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{4}$ for $n \geq 1$.

The sequence $a_n = 2^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)$ converges. To see this, we may observe (through some messy calculations) that $0 < \Delta a_n < \log(10/9) 2^{-(n + 1)}$. This implies that $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing and, by summing over $n$, that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded. Specifically, $a_{n + 1} < a_1 + \log(10/9)\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 2^{-(k + 1)} = \frac{1}{2} \log(5/3)$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq \frac{1}{2} \log(5/3)$. Numerical evidence suggests that this is a reasonably good bound.

This can be generalized. The sequence $a_n = d^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)$ converges for all real $d \geq 2$. This can be seen by computing its forward difference:
\begin{equation}
    \Delta a_n = d^{-(n + 1)} [\log(1 + 1/4(e_n - 1/2)^2) - (d - 2) \log(e_n - 1/2)].
\end{equation}
If $d > 2$, then we can show that the sequence is eventually strictly decreasing. ($\Delta a_n = d^{-(n + 1)} D_n$ for suitably defined $D_n$, and it can be checked that $e^{D_n}$ will eventually be less than $1$; hence $D_n < 0$ eventually.) Since it is also positive it must converge. This tells us nothing about *what* it converges to, though.

**Can we find "good" bounds of $\lim_{n \to \infty} d^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)$ for arbitrary reals $d \geq 2$?**

In particular, I suspect that $\lim_{d \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} d^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2) = 0$. A bound that allowed us to prove this would be nice.

Comment: Your $\{ e_n \}$ is often called _Sylvester's sequence_, see e.g. [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000058) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy, it's just a product of limits. For $d>2$, you have $d^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)=(\frac{2}{d})^n 2^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)$. But $(\frac{2}{d})^n$ converges to zero while $2^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)$ converges to a finite limit. So $d^{-n} \log(e_n - 1/2)$ converges to zero.

Comment: Way easier than I thought! This also shows divergence when $0 < d < 2$, since $2/d > 1$.